# Port USB 3 slow

Tags: usb

I have a T-Bao TBOOK MN25 Mini PC AMD 16GB RAM . It works well however I have an issue.
It has six USB ports and four of them USB 3.0 (plus 2 USB 2.0) . I attached a portable SAMSUNG SSD to port USB 3.0 and I can trasnfer data from internal M.2 NVMe 512GB to my Samsung SSD at only 30MB/s .
If I connect my SAMSUNG SSD to my desktop , I can transfer from internal M.2 NVMe to my Samsung SSD
at about 350MB/s .

Why the USB 3.0 ports in T-Bao TBOOK MN25 are running such as an USB 2.0 port ? Are these fake USB 3.0 ports ?

Comment: Could be fake or mislabeled, or could be the processor is slow. Try all USB ports to see if one is better or worse than others.

Comment: I tried and the single USB 3.0 port on the front works correctly and I reach a 350M/s .
Could it be an invalid bios setting or outdated bios ?

Comment: My guess, then, is that specs for the the device have changed (face-saving way of saying they prevaricate)  and there is only one true USB 3.0 port. There are inexpensive hubs to provide additional 3.0 ports, though you're stuck with using only that in front for high throughput (unless you want to open the box and add a USB 3.0 extension cable through a hole in back... requires micro-soldering technique).